# Not able to clone a new repository to a directory in terminal (Mac)

Tags: git, github, ssh, git-clone, repo

I am trying to clone a repo from GitHub into a directory on my mac's terminal. I make sure that I am in the correct directory on my terminal, then I go to my repo on GitHub, press the green "clone" box in the upper right, select SSH key and copy the value, then use the command in my terminal: "$ git clone <(copied SSH value)>" and get the following error: "zsh: parse error near `/n'"

Why am I receiving this error and how do I fix it? I know that parse error means it is a syntax error, but I don't understand how I have a syntax error if all I did was copy a value. Is there something else that I'm missing? I followed all the right steps from my bootcamp work.

Thanks to anyone who can help!

Comment: Did you also type `$` into the terminal?

Comment: No that is just what is automatically on my terminal, I only typed what came after that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you did

```
git clone <(copied_SSH_value)>
```

please no < nor >

```
git clone copied_SSH_value
```

for example

```
git clone https://github.com/pimcore/demo.git
```

Comment: Okay, so I should try it without the brackets?

Comment: Okay I tried it without the brackets and it worked! Thank you so much!